# Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was coding and i got stuck on this error. It keeps giving me that error "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues." on the .setValues line which doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is my code.

```
var finalPercentage5 = percantage5.map(x => [x]);
    Logger.log(values.length)
    Logger.log(finalPercentage5)
    Logger.log(finalPercentage5[4][0])
    for (var row=3; row<values.length; row++) { 
      if (M4.includes(values[row][0])) {
      var i=0;
          Logger.log(finalPercentage5[i][0])
        ss.getRange(row+3, 28).setValues(finalPercentage5[i][0]);
        i++;
              
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug it and it seem to me it is a number!

Here is a picture of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG32u.png)

Would really appreciate the help

If you any questions please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: setValues() expects a 2D array of row and column values.  `finalPercentage5[i][0]` is a single value.  Did you want setValue() instead?  As a note the use of setValue() may result in a slow down in performance.

Comment: but shouldnt it become a 2 D array after using var finalPercentage5 = percantage5.map(x => [x]);?

Comment: Yes but still your only using one element of the array `finalPercentage5[i][0]`

Comment: ok is there another method to use other than setValues to set the values of  a 1 D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
ss.getRange(row+3, 28).setValues(finalPercentage5[i][0]);
```

with:

```
ss.getRange(row+3, 28).setValue(finalPercentage5[i][0]);
```